# How do i remove a frameLayout in code?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to remove a framelayout containing a textview from the screen such that all the other layouts move up and take it's place.  Here is the layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etWarning"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="109dp"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:ems="10"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

        </FrameLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="10dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvReasonLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/ndr_Reason"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />


            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinNDRreasons"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>

               <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvQueston"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:text="Extra question goes here"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etResponse"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/cmdDoneNDR"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/cmd_done" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The top layout is the one I want to be able to add/remove with the other layouts moving up if it's not there.

Do I need a framelayout at all?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

give framelayout an id, and in your java activity code, set that view's setvisibility to gone.

or

actually since you only have one view inside that framelayout, you might just wanna do

```
etWarning.setVisibility(View.GONE); // this is for gone

etWarning.setVisibility(View.VISBLE); // this is to show it
```

hope this helps

Comment: I can make it invisible - but this does not 'remove' the frame so that the other layouts all move up into its original space.  Any thoughts?